# Ruby string to number keep format

Tags: ruby

I have a number stored as a sting e.g. `"2,65424.00"` Is there a way to convert it to a float number `2,65424.00` and keep the format?

Comment: That is an unusual format for a number. The question is also slightly confusing - could you please elaborate, perhaps just explain where your data is coming from, and where you want to display it? If you wish to use this value as a number, are you expecting to perform any math operations on it (in which case it could not be displayed exactly the same). Ruby numbers don't include a stored format but there are many ways to display them formatted. But likewise it is very easy to display a string without quotes if that is all you need to do. Just `puts s` (where `s` is your string).

Comment: No. `2,65424.00` is not a valid Ruby expression. In other words, such Ruby object does not exist. Hence there is no way to convert a string into such thing.

Answer (score 2):

No, the internal representation cannot be changed like this. The only way to approach this to write a `to_s` method for the `Float` and `Fixnum`. For example:

```
class Float
  def to_s
    # your formatting: sprintf("...", self)
  end
end
```

Since you want to do get the same representations on Fixnum you could then convert the Fixnum into a Float and then base the `to_s` method on the `to_s` method of Float.

```
class Fixnum
  def to_s
     self.to_f.to_s
  end
end
```

This way, you get the representation, through calling `to_s` on your Float

```
265424.to_s
=> "2,65424.00"
```

, or when you use interpolation:

```
 "When you write it like this #{265424}"
 => "When you write it like this 2,65424.00"
```

To my mind this is the proper approach, because you want an individual representation of your numbers. That is fine, but then this individual representation should be implemented at the string level, because if you want to display something nicely through formation, that's what strings are for.

Also it might be questionable to use this monkey patching approach, it depends whether you want to provide a library, etc. Maybe it would be fine if you just design a dedicated format method that takes the numbers and prints them formatted.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can not save float value with ',' as a delimiter in mysql
```

However you can do something like following

```
"2,65424.00".gsub(',', '').to_f # 265424.0
```

Comment: Thats true. '%.2f' % '2,65­424.00'.de­lete(',').­to_f You can also use this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your string object with `string.to_i` for integer or `string.to_f` for float.

Comment: Hmm you are right.. but don't help OP... :)